# htmlファイルでurlの内容によって条件分岐

Tags: javascript, html

大変お世話になっております。以下の様なhtmlファイルがあり、下部にある記述でurlから取得したp_idの値の内容（例：1、か2）によって、その上にあるinclud1.js、かinclud2.jsを条件分岐させたいのですが、具体的にどのような記述にすればよろしいかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includ1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includ2.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
const url = new URL(location.href);
const p_id = url.searchParams.get("p_id");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('p_id ').value = p_id;   
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

＊ご教授により試した記述

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
const url = new URL(location.href);
const p_id = url.searchParams.get("p_id");

const script = document.createElement('script');
if (p_id == 1) {
  script.src = 'includ1.js';
} else {
  script.src = 'includ2.js';
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('p_id ').value = p_id;   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 読み込むJavaScriptファイルをinclud1.jsかinclud2.jsで切り替えたいという意味でしょうか

Comment: PHPやRubyなどのサーバサイドの言語を利用すれば、GETパラメータから出力するHTML変更することは割と簡単そうですが、サーバサイドの言語は利用できないという前提でしょうか

Comment: ご多忙のなかコメントを頂きまして大変感謝いたします。現在、上記のinclude1.jsだけで表示されているhtmlのページがあります。”その状態からカスタマイズして、urlの値によってinclude1.jsかinclude2.jsを使い分けることができるかどうか”と考えてのご質問でございます。説明不足で大変恐縮でございます。

Comment: @int32_t 様が書かれている通り、if文の前にurl,p_idの取得処理を記載してみていください。

Answer (score 1):

動的に`script`要素を挿入すれば可能です。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
const url = new URL(location.href);
const p_id = url.searchParams.get("p_id");

const script = document.createElement('script');
if (p_idに関する条件) {
  script.src = 'includ1.js';
} else {
  script.src = 'includ2.js';
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

挿入したスクリプトが非同期に実行されますが、それが困る場合は`script`要素の`load`イベントを待って対処します。

Comment: int32_t様、ご回答大変感謝いたします。ご教授頂いたように試してみました（上記に補足）がページを開くと白い画面になり、どこか問題があるようです。条件分岐、およびinclude1.jsの読み込み、がなされていない様なのですが、問題点は見当たりますでしょうか。

Comment: @baseballjapan 私が書いたとおりの順番のコードにしてください。p_idの代入よりも後でscript要素を作ってください。

Comment: int32_t様、前回の投稿の際、間違って貼り付けしておりましたが、やはり上記補足の記述で白い画面が表示されます。継続して試しておりますが、ご助言はございますでしょうか。

Comment: ブラウザの開発者ツールでscript要素が期待通りの形で挿入されているか確認してください。そのあとは includ1.js includ2.js の内容がわからないとなんとも言えません。中で DOMContentLoaded を待ってたりするとダメかもしれないですね。

Comment: int32_t様、お時間頂き感謝いたします。条件分岐でinclude2.jsを使わず、両方をinclude1.js（カスタマイズ前の状態で機能している）にしても白画面表示ですので、if文がまず機能していないと思われます。次に、if (p_id == 1) {}else{}を削除し、 script.src = 'includ1.js';だけ配置しても白画面表示になります。以上から構文自体のどこかに問題があるのではと考え、いろいろと試しておりますが、どうにも分かりません。

Comment: include1.jsをシンプルな構文だけにして、デバックしてはどうでしょうか？例えばalert("読み込み完了！")にしてみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: `script.onload` にコールバック入れないと使い物にならないのでは

Comment: @baseballjapan さん、条件分岐側よりは、includ1.js の内容に依存した問題です。その内容しだいで対処は違うので、ご自分でデバッグするか、includ1.jsのおおまかな構成を開示するかしてください。

Comment: int32_t様、そして皆様、お忙しい中、特に週末にかけて無理難題を突き付けてしまい恐縮です、また詳細にご教授頂きまして本当に為になります。これからはやっている側である当事者の問題になりますので、int32_t様のおっしゃる通りデバッグしながら試してまいりたいと思います。様々な記述方法、指針等をお示しいただきまして本当に感謝いたします。